# Is there more leaf litter in tropical decisuous forests or temperate deciduous forests

Tags: climate-change, forest

I want to run an experiment: collect leafs in forests to try to stabilize them and prevent from rotting and emitting greenhouse gases.

I live in an area with temperate deciduous forest and have a fair idea of annual leaf litter production.

But how does that compare to tropical deciduous forest (and any other forest for that matter)?

Comment: So, you want to take valuable biomass out of the system in order to stabilize the system? Sounds like a bad idea to me, at least in tropical forests, but hey...

Comment: @Erik Totally agree. The goal is to stabilize the litter, not the forest system, the system will inevitably change, but "the hope" is that the producing part will not be damaged much. My reasoning is this: 1. We have old trees in old parks, where all the fallen leafs are collected and taken away, so at least for some species it's OK not to have litter decompose in the soil nearby. 2. We can replace some of the nutrients lost by manure or other fertilizer.

Comment: Geoengineering, even on such a small scale, is always a bad idea, since we know shit about feedbacks and tipping points.

Answer (score 1):

Biomass tend to be superior, however it's gone fast. Tropical moist forests have [little](https://mongabay-images.s3.amazonaws.com/1200/indonesia/indonesia_sulawesi_170358.jpg) leaf litter, because of the climate and humidity; dead organic litter [decomposes](https://www.sidmartinbio.org/how-the-tropical-forest-decomposition-rate-is-more-than-temperate-forest/) fairly fast. These organisms thrive in the warm, moist environment and it's seldom dry, so fungi proliferate uninpuned and are able to decompose organic matter very rapidly. Waste that would typically take one year to decompose in a regular temperate forest would decompose within six weeks in the tropics.

In the tropics, leaves fallen will dissappear in six weeks.
Temperate: one year
cooler range temperate: 2-3 years
Cold boreal region: Decades
Mediterranean climate: Periodic Fire deals with aiding decomposition

Comment: thank you very much!